# Django: the value of list_display[4] refers to 'age', which is not a callable, etc

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to extend the User model to add additional attributes to my "Person" model when I create instances of it, and I keep getting the following errors:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'polls.admin.PersonAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'age', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PersonAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.User'.
<class 'polls.admin.PersonAdmin'>:(admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[5]' refers to 'city', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PersonAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.User'.
<class 'polls.admin.PersonAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[6]' refers to 'state', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PersonAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.User'.
```

Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """ The model which defines a user of the application. Contains important
    information like name, email, city/state, age, etc """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Create_account view:

```
def create_account(request):
    # function to allow a user to create their own account
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # sets a new user and gives them a username
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"],
                    email=request.POST["email"],
                    first_name=request.POST["first_name"],
                    last_name=request.POST["last_name"],
                    age=request.POST["age"],
                    city=request.POST["city"],
                    state=request.POST["state"]
                    )

        # sets an encrypted password
        new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
        # adds the new user to the database
        Person.objects.create(user=new_user,
                          first_name=str(request.POST.get("first_name")),
                          last_name=str(request.POST.get("last_name")),
                          email=str(request.POST.get("email")),
                          age=str(request.POST.get("age")),
                          city=str(request.POST.get("city")),
                          state=str(request.POST.get("state"))
                          )
        new_user.is_active = True
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('../')
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

Snippets of admin.py:

```
class PersonInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """ Details a person in line. """
    model = Person
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'person'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """ Defines a Person's information on the admin site
    with displays listed below. """
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'city', 'state')
    inlines = (PersonInline, )
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Have you registered this admin class `PersonAdmin` ?

Comment: Yes:                                                                               admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, PersonAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Answer, AnswerAdmin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `admin.site.register(User, PersonAdmin)`, since `User` and `Person` are not the same model. Also, it looks like you are trying to include these Person model fields inside the User admin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class PersonInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """ Details a person in line. """
    model = Person
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'person'

    fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'city', 'state')

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PersonInline
    ]

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove from the app's admin.py file, a ManyToMany field that I defined in the model, and commented out that app's include () in the project's urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

`<class 'polls.admin.PersonAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'age', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PersonAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'auth.User'.`

What do above lines tell is that,

- age must be attribute of PersonAdmin class
- or attribute or method declared inside auth.User file

Also check for some typos in the code. I named slug in models.py and Slug in admin.py and it generated the same error.